# Local unit testing with Mockito in Android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

Can someone please show me a working unit test om this code, using mockito? Im new to testing in Android studio and could really need some help.

```
public class PreferenceHelper {

public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "EDUBACK_PREFS";
public static final String PREF_KEY_IS_STUDENT = "PREF_KEY_IS_STUDENT";
private final SharedPreferences mPref;

public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
    mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}


public void setIsStudent(boolean isStudent) {
    mPref.edit().putBoolean(PREF_KEY_IS_STUDENT, isStudent).apply();
}


public boolean getIsStudent() {
    return mPref.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_IS_STUDENT, true); // Default true
}}
```

Comment: What do you want to test? PreferenceHelper class? Or you want to mock PreferenceHelper when it is using in other classes?

Comment: I want to test the PreferenceHelper class

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not necessary to use mockito here.

You can test your class something like that (for assertions I use `org.assertj:assertj-core:3.5.2` library):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class PreferenceHelperTest {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        sharedPreferences = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Test
    public void setIsStudent_whenIsStudentIsTrue() {
        preferenceHelper.setIsStudent(true);
        assertThat(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_IS_STUDENT, false)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void setIsStudent_whenIsStudentIsFalse() {
        preferenceHelper.setIsStudent(false);
        assertThat(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_IS_STUDENT, true)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    public void getIsStudent_whenIsStudentIsNull() {
        boolean getIsStudent = preferenceHelper.getIsStudent();
        assertThat(getIsStudent).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void getIsStudent_whenIsStudentIsFalse() {
        preferenceHelper.setIsStudent(false);
        boolean getIsStudent = preferenceHelper.getIsStudent();
        assertThat(getIsStudent).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    public void getIsStudent_whenIsStudentIsTrue() {
        preferenceHelper.setIsStudent(true);
        boolean getIsStudent = preferenceHelper.getIsStudent();
        assertThat(getIsStudent).isTrue();
    }
}
```